# Can two positive ions be next to each other in a formula?

Tags: oxidation-state, chemical-formula

Let's say I want to find the oxidation numbers of the atoms in a chemical formula.

For example: In $\ce{H3AsO3}$,

Oxygen has a $-2$ charge. They're $3$ of them, so its $-6$

Hydrogen has a $+1$ charge. They're $3$ of them, so its $+3$.

So arsenic must have a charge of $+3$ for all the charges to add up to be $0$? Correct?

However, my professor keeps telling me to keep the positive oxidation numbers away from each other. I thought it only applied when drawing Lewis structures or resonance structures.

Is that a rule when writing a formula?

Comment: He could have told that two vowels can't be next to each other in a word. That's about as reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can two positive ions be next to each other in a formula?

Yes, there are many examples of this, $\ce{HNO3}$ for instance

> So Arsenic must have a charge of 3+ for all the charges to add up to
>   be 0? Correct?

Yes, that's correct

> However, my professor keeps telling me to keep the positive oxidation
>   numbers away from each other. Is that a rule when writing a formula?

It's not a rule that I'm familiar with.  Here is a [link](https://scilearn.sydney.edu.au/fychemistry/iChem/inorganic_nomenclature.shtml) to a nice, concise listing of the rules for writing formulas for inorganic compounds.

> I thought it only applied when drawing Lewis structures or resonance
>   structures.

Yes, it certainly applies in those two cases

Comment: I think in $\ce{HNO3}\equiv\ce{(HO-)N(=O)2}$ no two positive partial charges are next to each other, so that would not provide an example, but $\ce{HNO}$ would.

Comment: So would you say that I can write $\ce{H3AsO3}$ as $\ce{AsH3O3}$ and it wouldn't make a difference because my Lewis diagram would remain the same?

Comment: @Martin  I meant it in the nomenclature sense.  In other words, in the molecular formula an $\ce{H}$ (+1) is written next to an $\ce{N}$ (+5)

Comment: @Mark  No, see the rules for constructing molecular formulas in the link I provided.

Comment: @Mark There are the official rules for writing sum formulas, like in the link that ron provided. There are some other ways of writing them, like the [Hill system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_system) that is quite common in Organic Chemistry. Also the Lewis formula is only one representation of a molecule, and there are a lot of examples where this approach fails (see hypercoordinate species).// ron - I guess I did not see that it is a question about the notation, I thought this would be a question about actual charges.

Comment: @Martin  In the title of Mark's question he writes "in a formula" so that's how I approached it.

Comment: You are a far better reader than me ;) After your comment, I revisited the title and it was obvious after that, and then you got my vote...